# Responsive Tabs to Accordion - open tab from different page

Tags: jquery, tabs, responsive-design, accordion

I've just implemented this code (https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion) for converting a set of tabs to an accordion layout on smaller screens. It works really well except I need to be able to specify which tab/accordion is open when linking from another page.

This is the website I'm working on - http://www.eventsthatmatter.co.uk/new/

When clicking on one of the four "service" types on the homepage I need it to open the corresponding tab on the services page. Currently it defaults to the first tab.

The question has been asked on the author's GitHub page but has not yet been answered. Just wondering if anyone on here can help. I can see on here that the question has been asked relating to other jquery examples of tabs and accordions but due to my lack of JQuery experience I'm not sure how to use that advice to achieve it with this script.

This is the html:

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
        <li id="tab01">...</li>
        <li id="tab02">...</li>
        <li id="tab03">...</li>
        <li id="tab04" class="last">...</span></li>
    </ul> 

    <div class="resp-tabs-container">  

        <div id="services01">...</div>

        <div id="services02">...</div>

        <div id="services03">...</div>

        <div id="services04">...</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And the JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        easyResponsiveTabs: function (options) {
            //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                type: 'default', //default, vertical, accordion;
                width: 'auto',
                fit: true,
                closed: false,
                activate: function(){}
            }
            //Variables
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);            
            var opt = options, jtype = opt.type, jfit = opt.fit, jwidth = opt.width, vtabs = 'vertical', accord = 'accordion';

            //Main function
            this.each(function () {
                var $respTabs = $(this);
                var $respTabsList = $respTabs.find('ul.resp-tabs-list');
                $respTabs.find('ul.resp-tabs-list li').addClass('resp-tab-item');
                $respTabs.css({
                    'display': 'block',
                    'width': jwidth
                });

                $respTabs.find('.resp-tabs-container > div').addClass('resp-tab-content');
                jtab_options();
                //Properties Function
                function jtab_options() {
                    if (jtype == vtabs) {
                        $respTabs.addClass('resp-vtabs');
                    }
                    if (jfit == true) {
                        $respTabs.css({ width: '100%', margin: '0px' });
                    }
                    if (jtype == accord) {
                        $respTabs.addClass('resp-easy-accordion');
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tabs-list').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                }

                //Assigning the h2 markup to accordion title
                var $tabItemh2;
                $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content').before("<h2 class='resp-accordion' role='tab'><span class='resp-arrow'></span></h2>");

                var itemCount = 0;
                $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion').each(function () {
                    $tabItemh2 = $(this);
                    var innertext = $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item:eq(' + itemCount + ')').html();
                    $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion:eq(' + itemCount + ')').append(innertext);
                    $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion:eq(' + itemCount + ')').addClass('resp-accordion-' + (itemCount));
                    $tabItemh2.attr('aria-controls', 'tab_item-' + (itemCount));
                    itemCount++;
                });

                //Assigning the 'aria-controls' to Tab items
                var count = 0,
                    $tabContent;
                $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item').each(function () {
                    $tabItem = $(this);
                    $tabItem.attr('aria-controls', 'tab_item-' + (count));
                    $tabItem.attr('role', 'tab');

                    //First active tab, keep closed if option = 'closed' or option is 'accordion' and the element is in accordion mode 
                    if(options.closed !== true && !(options.closed === 'accordion' && !$respTabsList.is(':visible')) && !(options.closed === 'tabs' && $respTabsList.is(':visible'))) {                  
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item').first().addClass('resp-tab-active');
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion').first().addClass('resp-tab-active');
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content').first().addClass('resp-tab-content-active').attr('style', 'display:block');
                    }

                    //Assigning the 'aria-labelledby' attr to tab-content
                    var tabcount = 0;
                    $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content').each(function () {
                        $tabContent = $(this);
                        $tabContent.attr('aria-labelledby', 'tab_item-' + (tabcount));
                        tabcount++;
                    });
                    count++;
                });

                //Tab Click action function
                $respTabs.find("[role=tab]").each(function () {
                    var $currentTab = $(this);
                    $currentTab.click(function () {

                        var $tabAria = $currentTab.attr('aria-controls');

                        if ($currentTab.hasClass('resp-accordion') && $currentTab.hasClass('resp-tab-active')) {
                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content-active').slideUp('', function () { $(this).addClass('resp-accordion-closed'); });
                            $currentTab.removeClass('resp-tab-active');
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (!$currentTab.hasClass('resp-tab-active') && $currentTab.hasClass('resp-accordion')) {
                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-active').removeClass('resp-tab-active');
                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content-active').slideUp().removeClass('resp-tab-content-active resp-accordion-closed');
                            $respTabs.find("[aria-controls=" + $tabAria + "]").addClass('resp-tab-active');

                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content[aria-labelledby = ' + $tabAria + ']').slideDown().addClass('resp-tab-content-active');
                        } else {
                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-active').removeClass('resp-tab-active');
                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content-active').removeAttr('style').removeClass('resp-tab-content-active').removeClass('resp-accordion-closed');
                            $respTabs.find("[aria-controls=" + $tabAria + "]").addClass('resp-tab-active');
                            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content[aria-labelledby = ' + $tabAria + ']').addClass('resp-tab-content-active').attr('style', 'display:block');
                        }
                    });
                    //Window resize function                   
                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion-closed').removeAttr('style');
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers,
Kev

Comment: I've managed to get it working using my own horrible hacky javascript which changes classes based on a url parameter (?tab=x), but I'm sure there is a far more correct way to do this if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

```
var vtab=3;

//remove the activated tab

var areatext = $("ul.resp-tabs-list").find(".resp-tab-active").first().attr('aria-controls');

$('#verticalTab').find('[aria-controls=' + areatext + ']').removeClass('resp-tab-active');

$('.resp-tabs-container').find('[aria-labelledby=' + areatext + ']').removeClass('resp-tab-content-active').removeAttr("style");

//activate the target tab

$("#verticalTab li[aria-controls='tab_item-" + vtab + "']").addClass("resp-tab-active");

$("#verticalTab .resp-tabs-container div[aria-labelledby='tab_item-" + vtab + "']").addClass("resp-tab-content-active").attr("style", "display: block;");
```

Comment: Usually we like to see answers with a little bit of text that explains how/why the code answers the question that was asked. It helps make sure there's lasting value to the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with this code,

```
var stab = 2 // selected tab

lis = $("ul.resp-tabs-list > li");
lis.removeClass("resp-tab-active");
$("ul.resp-tabs-list li[aria-controls='tab_item-"+stab+"']").addClass("resp-tab-active");
divs = $("#tabs .resp-tabs-container > div");
divs.removeClass("resp-tab-content-active").removeAttr("style");
$("#tabs .resp-tabs-container div[aria-labelledby='tab_item-"+stab+"']").addClass("resp-tab-content-active").attr("style","display: block;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I had a similar issue but for when using horizontal tabs.

Here's my modification to the above code to set a default expanded tab:

```
//set default tab
  var vtab=0;
//remove the activated tab
  var areatext = $("ul.resp-tabs-list").find(".resp-tab-active").first().attr('aria-controls');
//activate the target tab
  $("#horizontalTab h2[aria-controls='tab_item-" + vtab + "']").addClass("resp-tab-active");
  $("#horizontalTab .resp-tabs-container div[aria-labelledby='tab_item-" + vtab + "']").addClass("resp-tab-content-active").attr("style", "display: block;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar. I needed that tab accordion to open from a form submit from the same tab on the same page. I used a $_GET variable and then if the variable is set I add the active class to the tab. I hope this helps others as the $_GET could come from a link also.

PHP:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['tab1'])){
        $tab1_active = "r-tabs-panel r-tabs-state-active";
     }
  ?>
```

Then within the tab

```
 <div id="tabs-1" <?php if(isset($tab1_active)){ echo 'class="'.$tab1_active.'"';}?>>
```

I added a hidden input for the variable.

```
<input type="hidden" value="tab1" name="tab1" />
```

Then you repeat for all the needed tabs.